# MySQL - Rows with the same values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that will show the below rows:

```
first_name   last_name     dept_no  hire_date   from_date
----------------------------------------------------------
Jianwen       Schiper       d004    1986-10-17  1986-10-17
Sanjiv        Zschoche      d004    1986-10-17  1986-10-17
Moty          Winter        d004    1991-04-28  1991-04-28
Zhilian       Ranst         d004    1991-04-28  1991-04-28
Jaewoo        Yoshimura     d004    1991-04-28  1991-04-28
Herbert       Zizka         d005    1985-03-21  1985-03-21
Arno          Luke          d005    1985-03-21  1985-03-21
Muzhong       Shokrollahi   d007    1985-09-05  1985-09-05
Isaac         Bael          d007    1985-09-05  1985-09-05
Mani          Cannata       d007    1989-06-21  1989-06-21
Lidong        Tomescu       d007    1989-06-21  1989-06-21
Taizo         Kitsuregawa   d007    1991-09-03  1991-09-03
Bodo          Tagansky      d007    1991-09-03  1991-09-03
```

In a few words I need the employees who were hired on the same date for the same department.
The following query gives me the employees with their first department and their hire date:

```
select first_name, last_name, dept_no, hire_date, from_date
from employees join dept_emp using(emp_no)
where hire_date = from_date 
order by hire_date, dept_no
```

I need to seperate those who were hired on the same date for the same department. I've tried too many queries but I couldn't get what I needed.
Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh it's not the data table, it's the expected result

Comment: I think I understand what `hire_date` is, but what is `from_date`?

Comment: And what tables do the columns belong to? I guess `first_name` and `last_name` are in `employees` and `dept_no`, `hire_date`, and `from_date` are in `dept_emp`. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner from_date is the date when the employee started working on the department

Comment: yes @ThorstenKettner you guessed it right exept the hire_date, it belong to employees too

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the answer you posted was too close! but it gives me 2 employees that doesn't fit and I can't understand why... But it's OK I'll try to fix it thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I noticed a flaw and had to delete my answer accordingly for I had no time to improve it. The problem was that the subquery looked for any from_dates, not only those matching hire_dates. I've updated my answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see employees hired together, then you can order the results:

```
select first_name, last_name, dept_no, hire_date, from_date
from employees join
     dept_emp
     using (emp_no)
order by dept_no, hire_date;
```

If you want dates where at least two employees were hired (and the employees on that date):

```
select first_name, last_name, dept_no, hire_date, from_date
from employees e join
     dept_emp d
     using (emp_no)
where exists (select 1
              from employees e2
              where e2.dept_no = e.dept_no and
                    e2.hire_date = e.hire_date and
                    e2.emp_no <> e.emp_no
             )
order by dept_no, hire_date;
```

Comment: Partly it's fuctioning. It shows what I need but it shows additional content

Comment: @Giannis Grigoriadis: Additional content? What do you mean? The second query should work for you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it shows all the data that I posted but it shows 11 more employees that don't fit to the expected result

Comment: @GiannisGrigoriadis . . . I don't get what you are looking for.  This should be showing all employees in a department that were hired with other employees on the same day.  Isn't that what you are asking for?

Comment: yes this is what I'm asking for but the result doesn't fit with the expected result but it's ok I'll try to fix that. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So this is about the initial hiring of employees and the departments they were then hired for. You assume the `dept_emp.from_date` to equal `employees.hire_date` for this case.

Unfortunately, with MySQL you have to write the same query twice, once as a main query and once as a subquery (where you would simply use `count(*) over ()` in other DBMS).

This is how to get employees with their first department:

```
select *
from employees e
join dept_emp de on de.emp_no = e.emp_no and de.from_date = e.hire_date
```

This is how to find first-department / from-date combinations with more than one entry:

```
select de.dept_no, de.from_date
from employees e
join dept_emp de on de.emp_no = e.emp_no and de.from_date = e.hire_date
group by de.dept_no, de.from_date
having count(*) > 1
```

This is the two combined:

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name, de.dept_no, e.hire_date, de.from_date
from employees e
join dept_emp de on de.emp_no = e.emp_no and de.from_date = e.hire_date
where (de.dept_no, de.from_date) in
(
  select de.dept_no, de.from_date
  from employees e
  join dept_emp de on de.emp_no = e.emp_no and de.from_date = e.hire_date
  group by de.dept_no, de.from_date
  having count(*) > 1
)
order by de.dept_no, e.hire_date
```